# Where is my xorg.conf file in my VBox virtual machine?

Tags: xorg, virtualbox, displaylink, x11

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 as a guest in a virtual machine in VirtualBox. I also installed guest additions.

My problem is that I can no longer find `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Where has the file gone...? Or more importantly, where do I modify the X11 settings to add a DisplayLink device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't have /etc/X11/xorg.conf by default but autodetects all settings. But if you create that file and insert the settings you want to change X.org will use it.

Answer (score 0):

You will find some components of the `xorg.conf` in the directory `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d`.  Seen `man xorg` for a list of files and directories which may contain configuration components.

The rest of the configuration is auto generated. The configuration may be modified by system configuration events.  The most likely case would be if an input device is added to the system.